# ReactJS RSS Feed to Json converter

Tags: reactjs, rss

I am using the following code to convert RSS feed to JSON file:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Feed from 'rss-to-json'

const App = () => {    

const getFeed = () => {
  Feed.load('https://www.reddit.com/.rss', function(err, rss){
    console.log(rss);
    });
}


  return(
    <Button
      onClick = {() => getFeed()}
       variant="outlined">
      Submit
    </Button>
  ) 

}

export default App;
```

But I am getting the following error in cosole:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I am not sure how to approach this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be need to setup OAUTH  for authentication, when you are accessing the rss url above. Other endpoints are working fine. See here - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-worker-u8zo9

You can get more details regarding OAUTH setup for  Reddit API's [here](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/oauth2)